# How to add a column via a query which counts the total rows with a specific criteria in a table with circular relationship in MS ACCESS 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a simple table "Employees" with this fields:

```
ID, ParentID, Name
```

ParentID is Nullable since an employee may have no Manager.
This table has a one-to-many relationship with itself:

```
ID --one--to--many--> ParentID
```

Now I want a query which returns this columns:

Name, Count of rows where their ParentID equals to the current row ID (the row is the manager of that rows)

Sample Table:

```
ID | ParentID | Name
======================
 1 |     0    | John
----------------------
 2 |     1    | Bob
----------------------
 3 |     1    | Alice
----------------------
 4 |     3    | Jack
```

This way I can find an employee is the manager of how many other employees.
The result should be something like this:

```
Name  | Count of Employees
==========================
John  |   2
--------------
Bob   |   0
--------------
Alice |   1
--------------
Jack  |   0
```

How can I achieve this in MS ACCESS 2007?
* I have tried built-in query builder without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want a count of how many employees a manager has?

You will have to join the table to itself. It can be done in the query builder but the SQL statement will be easier to put here.

```
SELECT [Employees].Name, [Employees].ParentID, [Employees].Name, Count([Employees1].ParentID) AS NoOfEmployees
FROM [Employees] LEFT JOIN [Employees] AS [Employees1] ON [Employees].ID = [Employees1].ParentID
GROUP BY [Employees].ID, [Employees].ParentID, [Employees].Name;
```

I added the two other columns from the tables and renamed the count column to NoOfEmployees.

Comment: Yes. Just wanna add a column to show how many employees a manager has

Comment: You want this count column in the table?

Comment: No, the table should remain intact. I wanna a query same as the table plus that column (count of employees) added to the result.

Comment: This SQL statement will do that. Open a new query in desgin mode and select SQL view and past this.

Comment: I tested yot query. MS ACCESS opens a dialog and asks for a parameter `Employees.Name` !

Comment: Sorry first field should be ID. If it is asking for a parameter it means that field is not in the table. Make sure the table is Employees and the field is Name.

Comment: I ran it and got the right results based on the table you provided. How are the results incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
 SELECT t1.ID, t2.ParentID 
 FROM Employees t1 
 LEFT JOIN Employees t2
 ON t1.ID = t2.ParentID
```

To count you would say

```
 SELECT t1.ID, Count(t2.ParentID)
 FROM Employees t1 
 LEFT JOIN Employees t2
 ON t1.ID = t2.ParentID
 GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Comment: There's only one Table: `Employees`

Comment: Look at the query, it only has one table, but it has two aliases. `Employess t1` means table Employees alias t1.

Comment: Then how to define those aliases ?

Comment: I do not understand you, the aliases are defined in the sql I posted above, if the names are correct, you can paste the sql in the sql view of the query design window.

Comment: If you want to try this yourself, add the employees table twice to the query design window and drag ID in the first table to the ParentID on the second table, MS Access will assign aliases for you.